# Redirecting error using .htaccess

Tags: redirect

rewriting the url RewriteRule ^about/ /about.php [L,R=301] but the page is accessed via /about.php directly also. Please help to how to redirect .php file

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+about\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /about/ [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **free .htaccess Redirect Generator**:

http://htaccessredirect.net/

with this tool you can easily create your redirection code for .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rule to hidden redirect:

```
#use [L] to hidden [R] to shown redirect
RewriteRule ^(about|faq|home)/?$ $1.php [L]

#to prevent access from about.php simply do this:
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ $1/ [R=301]
#you need to know 301 redirect will be cached with browser for long time
#so if you change rule - will be no effect for some visitors
```