# Rewrite URL for specific file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a way to remove the extension of a file through .htaccess. For example, I want `http://example.com/blog.php` to be rewritten to `http://example.com/blog`. BUT I only want blog.php's extension to be removed, not any other file.

I tried this...

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [L]
```

But it lets `http://example.com/blog` AND `http://example.com/blog.php` to be loaded. It doesn't rewrite the URL. \

I mainly want to do this so I don't have to go through all my code, changing all the links going to `http://example.com/blog.php` to `http://example.com/blog`

Comment: `RewriteCond ^blog.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ blog.php [L, QSA]` possibly?

Comment: That gives a 500 internal server error.

Comment: [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1992191/2518525)

Comment: Nothing there helped. I am looking for a way to rewrite the URL to `example.com/blog` when and ONLY when `example.com/blog.php` is called.

Comment: Set up a .htaccess 301 redirect from `blog.php` to `/blog` then?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry, I don't know anything about the syntax .htaccess files are written in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18020273/2518525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't rewrite the URL.

Rewriting happens internally within the server. Your rule rewrites the request URI from `/blog` to `/blog.php`. It doesn't interact with the browser *at all*. What you are asking for is an external redirect. You want mod_rewrite to return a redirect to the browser and have the browser *send a whole different request*. That can be done using:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+blog\.php
RewriteRule ^ /blog [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Cool! This worked! Now, is there a way to do this for a group of .php files with only having to change one or two lines of code? Note: I don't want to do this for all .php files, only a few.

Comment: @Locke change the `/+blog\.php` to `/+([^\?\ ])\.php` and the `/blog` in the rule to `%`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog.php [R=301,L]
```

Basically, if someone accesses your site using the URL `<yoursite>/blog`, the .htaccess will rewrite it to `<yoursite>/blog.php`